# Warning HTTP Header - legal agent string format

Tags: http

I've just set a Warning HTTP header for the first time. In the `System.Net` .NET namespace, there's a type `WarningHeaderValue` with this constructor:

```
WarningHeaderValue(int code, string agent, string text)
```

But it throws on my agent string saying

> The format of value 'Company Name .NET Origin' is invalid.

What format is legal for the agent? I couldn't glean anything useful from the HTTP spec.

> ```
>  warn-agent = ( uri-host [ ":" port ] ) / pseudonym
>                  ; the name or pseudonym of the server adding
>                  ; the Warning header field, for use in debugging
>                  ; a single "-" is recommended when agent unknown
>  warn-text  = quoted-string
>  warn-date  = DQUOTE HTTP-date DQUOTE
> ```

What's missing in all these arcane specifications are examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, quoted-string  means include quotes within the string.
So instead of: `"Deprecated API"` , it would be `"\"Deprecated API\""`

Full example:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await base.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

string message = $"\"Deprecated API : use {NewUri} instead.\"";
response.Headers.Warning.Add(new WarningHeaderValue(299, "-", message));
return response;
```